# Предварительная загрузка всех изображений

Tags: css3, javascript, изображения, html5

Скажем, у меня есть изображение на сайте, при наведении на который мышью оно меняется (подгружется новое вместо него)
И такая проблема, что при первом наведении оно дергается, тк браузер его загружает только по требованию (наведению)
Вопрос: как загрузить такие изображения вместе со всеми, заранее? а не при наведении. чтобы не было эффекта дергания.
И вдовесок вопрос, как реализовать это вооще сразу для всех фото а не для каждого по отдельности?
спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делайте наборы иконок в одном файле, так сделано вомногих проектах (jQuery UI, Bootstrap как пирмер)
Кроме того есть возможность создать объект

```
$img=new Image();
$img.src='icon-pack.png';
```

что подгрузит картинку заранее